# Eclipse Android error parsing XML: unblound prefix

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am an eclipse/android noob who just types in source code from a book. Currently, I am having problems with this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
anndroid:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="example.firstandroid.MainActivity"
>
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/insa"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="20pt"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/anyouing"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="#0000ff"
    />
<Textview
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Good Morning"
    android:textcolor="#8000ff00"
    android:textsize="5mm"
    android:typeface="serif"
    />
```

writing this code gives me two "errors"-

1. error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
2. Unparsed aapt error(s): Check the console for output

Comment: Show the error of logcat ??

Comment: the last TextView is not capitalized, also the textSize property

Comment: i did capitalize the textview and textsize but i couldn't solve the problem yet.

Comment: It's a typo: `anndroid:layout_height="match_parent"` should be `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

Comment: @Áron Nemmondommegavezetéknevem thankyou so much!!! finally solved the problem. should look out for typos from now on.